# Open street map does not return address with many parameters in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap

I have the following problem, if I cross the street and number as an address I get a coordinate normally:

Map, Ok

[image]

The last address was: Lindolfo Azevedo Brito 191

But if I add more information such as a city named Brumado:

second result

[image]

My QML code:

```
    Plugin{
        id: osm
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter{name: "osm.useragent"; value: "IVarejo"}
        PluginParameter{name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"; value: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org"}
        PluginParameter{name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"; value: true}
    }

    Address{
        id: enderecoCliente
        street: rua
        city: cidade
    }

    GeocodeModel{
        id: geoModel
        plugin: osm
        autoUpdate: false

        onLocationsChanged: {

            if(count > 0){

                map.center = get(0).coordinate
                marker.coordinate = get(0).coordinate
                map.addMapItem(marker)

            }

        }

    }
```

C++

```
QQmlContext *context = ui->qwMapa->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("rua", data.value(0) + " " + data.value(1));
context->setContextProperty("cidade", data.value(3));

ui->qwMapa->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/qml/localizarcliente.qml"));
```

The code was a system for locating a company's customers that are stored in a given database.

**Edited**

I did the latest test, with a zip code addition it keeps working

Comment: Problem unclear. Please add the exact URLs for your geocoding requests. I guess you are querying Nominatim or a similar geocoding service.

Comment: @scai how i can get the url of my geocoding request?

Comment: I have no experience with this OSM plugin for Qt. However maybe you can enable debug options to log your HTTP(S) queries.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, problem was missing "Street" prefix in street name, when adding "Street" in street name query executes normally